# webpack разные точки входа

Tags: javascript, webpack

Я хочу создать файлы `index.html` и `card.html`, в которые будут подключаться `index.js` и `card.js` соответсвенно. [Ссылка на github](https://github.com/mihinov/githubDashboard)

Но у меня получается так, что в каждом html файле подключаются все javascript файлы, а также весь css

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="card.js"></script>
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const getFiles = function (dir, files_){
  files_ = files_ || [];
    var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    for (var i in files){
        var name = dir + '/' + files[i];
        if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()){
            getFiles(name, files_);
        } else {
            files_.push(name);
        }
    }
    return files_;
};

const pathSrc = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const pages = getFiles(pathSrc)
  .filter((item) => path.extname(item) === '.html');


module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: {
    index: './index/index',
    card: './card/card'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    library: '[name]'
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000
  },
  plugins: [
    ...pages.map(page => {
      return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: page,
        filename: path.basename(page)
      })
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
  ]
  }
};
```

Comment: уберите автодобавление скриптов и стилей в файл

Comment: @meine это где такое у меня?

Comment: у `HtmlWebpackPlugin` есть настройка: `inject`, по умолчанию она `true`, поставьте на `false`, самих файлах подключите то, что нужно, теперь это делается вручную

Comment: скорее всего просто неправильно указаны пути до `.css` файла

Comment: @meine благодарствую! Как раз то, чтобы начать писать код для своего приложения) Но я думал, что можно написать что-то автоматическое, типа я создаю папку index, в нём index.html, index.js, (index.css можно импортировать в js) и при компиляции оно собирается само. Может где-то можно посмотреть готовые конфиги?

Comment: думаю, что где-то на просторах интернета есть конфиги, а зачем вы так делаете? (разносите скрипты по отдельным страницам), берите один входной файл и оттуда двигайтесь, ненужное не включайте, нужное включайте

Comment: У меня несколько страниц сайта. Я просто изучил rxjs и начал писать код на нативном js с rxjs (без фреймворка) и нужно было сделать `card.html`, в котором свои стили и свой js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В плагине HtmlWebpacjPlugin есть опция, в которой нужно указать список чанков, которые будут импортированы в html.

Вроде называется chunks.